# DomCrawler filterXpath for emails

Tags: symfony, xpath, filter, domcrawler

In my project I am trying to use `filterXPath` for emails. So I get an E-Mail via IMAP and put the mail body into my `DomCrawler`.

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addHtmlContent($mail->textHtml); //mail html content utf8
```

Now to my issue. I only want the plain text of the mail body, but still remain all new lines spaces etc - the exact same as the mail looks just in plain text without html (still with \n\r etc).

For that reason I tried using `$crawler->filterXPath('//body/descendant-or-self::*/text()')` to get every text node inside the mail.

However my test-mail containts html like:

```
<p>&#13;
    <u>
        <span>
            <a href="mailto:mail@example.com">
                <span style="color:#0563C1">mail@example.com</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </u>
    <span>&#13;</span>
    <span>·</span>
    <span>
        <b>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">
                <span style="color:#0563C1">www.example.com</span>
            </a>
        </b>
    <p/>
    </span>
</p>&#13;
```

In my mail this looks like `mail@example.com · www.example.com` (in one single line).

With my `filterXPath` I get multiple nodes which result in following (multiple lines):

```
mail@example.com
· wwww.example.com
```

I know that probably the `&#13;` might be the problem, which is a `\r`, but since I can't change the html in the mail, I need another solution - **as mentioned before in the mail it is only a single line**.

**Please keep in mind, that my solution has to work for every mail - I do not know how the mail html looks like - it can change every time. So I need a generic solution.**

I already tried using `strip_tags` too - this does not change the result at all.

---

My current approach:

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addHtmlContent($mail->textHtml);

$text = "";
foreach ($crawler->filterXPath('//body/descendant-or-self::*/text()') as $element) {
    $part = trim($element->textContent);
    if($part) {
        $text .= "|".$part."|\n"; //to see whitespaces etc
    }
}
echo $text;

//OUTPUT
|mail@example.com|
|·|
| |
|www.example.com|
| |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($crawler);
$result = $xpath->query('(//span[not(descendant::*)])');

$text = "";
foreach ($result as $element) {
    $part = trim($element->textContent);
    if($part) {
        $text .= "|".$part."|"; //to see whitespaces etc
    }
}
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
|mail@example.com||Â·||www.example.com|
```

Answer (score -1):

Do note that you are dealing with two different ways to treat whitespace only text nodes: HTML has its own rules about if those are rendered (the difference are mainly between block elements and inline elements and also includes normalization) and XPATH works over a document tree provided by a parser (or DOM API) which has its own configuration about preserving or not those whitespace only text nodes. Taking this into account, one solution could be to use the [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string) function to get the string value of the element containing the email:

For this input:

```
<root>
<p>&#13;
    <u>
        <span>
            <a href="mailto:mail@example.com">
                <span style="color:#0563C1">mail@example.com</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </u>
    <span>&#13;</span>
    <span>·</span>
    <span>
        <b>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">
                <span style="color:#0563C1">www.example.com</span>
            </a>
        </b>
    <p/>
    </span>
</p>&#13;
</root>
```

This XPath expresion:

```
string(/root)
```

Outputs:

```
                mail@example.com




    ·



                www.example.com
```

Check in [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/9ff23576ca456f6cfed79b501682dc7a)